# Is it possible to use multiple cypher calls in the FROM clause using Apache-AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

The cypher() function returns a relational table, so a cypher call can be used alongside other tables in a query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, cypher('cypher_query1');
```

The query above works as expected. However, if I call the cypher function twice, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('cypher_query1'), cypher('cypher_query2');
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  table name "cypher" specified more than once
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If you could add more details on what you were trying to attempt with multiple cypher queries using FROM, it would make the answers more clarified. Alternatively, if my answer matched your requirements, that's great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems only 1 table and 1 Cypher query will work at the moment. The order doesn't matter (table, cypher() or cypher(), table). I do not know whether this is an intended design choice or not.

As for practical usage, I don't understand how what you are seeking would be useful? If you are looking to access another graph within your query you can already do that using JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph1', $$
CREATE (c: Customer { user: 'gomeZ', tags: 'dev' })
$$) as (v agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('graph2', $$
CREATE (s: Queries { user: 'gomeZ', keywords: ['java', 'c', 'python'] })
$$) as (v agtype);
```

```
SELECT graph1.u, graph1.t, graph2.k         
FROM cypher('graph1', $$
MATCH (c:Customer)
RETURN c.user, c.tags
$$) as graph1(u agtype, t agtype)
JOIN cypher('graph2', $$
MATCH (s:Queries)
RETURN s.user, s.keywords
$$) as graph2(u agtype, k agtype)
ON graph1.u = graph2.u;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Building on top of your suggestion, if I use 2 different cypher calls in the same FROM clause and specify distinct names for each of them (as graph1 and graph2 like in your example), that works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload multiple cypher queries in a single from clause in the following way

```
SELECT * FROM
cypher('graph1', $$
    CREATE (p: Person { name: 'Person1', email: 'abc@email.com'})
$$) as graph1(v agtype),
cypher('graph2', $$
    CREATE (d: Department { name: 'Marketing', office: 'NYC' })
$$) as graph2(v agtype);
```